# QML ScrollViewStyle width?

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, scrollview

I'd like to make a ScrollView's scroll bar wider than the default value, but I don't see any `width` properties, even as part of the `ScrollViewStyle` element's `frame` component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the scroll bar wider, you can change the following four properties in `ScrollViewStyle` with your custom components: `handle`, `scrollBarBackground`, `decrementControl`, and `incrementControl` (it may look weird if you do not change all of them). For example,

```
ScrollView {
    style: ScrollViewStyle {
        handle: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "red"
        }
        scrollBarBackground: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "black"
        }
        decrementControl: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "green"
        }
        incrementControl: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 50
            implicitHeight: 30
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image: custom scroll bar]

Comment: ...Meaning that I need to re-implement the entire appearance of the scroll-bars? Is there some way to just use the default grey-on-grey-with-arrows scheme, or an easy way to re-implement that?

Comment: In addition, as-is, this appears to cause several "`TextArea.qml:<line-number>: Unable to assigne [undefined] to <type>`" errors, and my screen flashes in a weird way. How can I figure out what a minimal complete working `ScrollViewStyle` would actually consist of?

Comment: .....actually, the reason this isn't working might be because I'm not using a `ScrollView` directly, I'm using a `TextArea`, which *inherits from* `ScrollView`. The only `style` member in `TextArea` [appears to be the one it inherits from `ScrollView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea-members.html), though, so I'm still not sure why I can't just assign a `ScrollViewStyle` to `TextView`'s `style` property.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to re-implement the entire appearance since QtQuick control style does not provide any method for you to override some of the properties (ex. width) in the default component. For `TextArea` style, try [TextAreaStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textareastyle.html), which inherits from `ScrollViewStyle`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changing `ScrollViewStyle` to `TextAreaStyle` works perfectly, without even defining any extra properties.