# QML TextView change scroll-bar style?

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview

I have a QML `TextArea` for which I'd like a wider scrollbar. `TextArea` inherits from `ScrollView`, and it appears that the only `style` member in the `TextArea` class is [inherited from `ScrollView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html), so I thought I could just assign a `ScrollViewStyle` to the `TextView`'s `style` member.

However, assigning [this suggested `ScrollViewStyle` example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36514659/1858225) to my `TextArea`'s `style` member triggers error messages and makes the screen flicker oddly.

Here are the error messages:

```
 file:///<qtpath>/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:766:32: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
 file:///<qtpath>/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:765:29: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
 file:///<qtpath>/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:764:20: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
 file:///<qtpath>/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:763:19: Unable to assign [undefined] to QFont
 file:///<qtpath>/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:762:25: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
 file:///<qtpath>/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TextArea.qml:725:24: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
```

What's going on? How do I assign a `ScrollViewStyle` to the `TextArea` properly (assuming this is indeed the problem)? (E.g., can I explicitly scope the `style` assignment somehow? `ScrollView.style: ScrollViewStyle { ...` gives the error "`Non-existent attached object`.") Alternatively, is there a simpler way to just *make the scroll bar wider* without getting into this whole mess?

I'm using 64-bit Qt 5.5.1 on Debian 7 Wheezy.

Comment: Also `TextAreaStyle` Inherits from `ScrollViewStyle`, which means the former has at least all the properties of the latter: you can simply rename the style `Item` from that link to `TextAreaStyle` and that's it, it should work out of the box. The parent style is probably missing some properties (the `undefined` warnings).

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Ah! Thank you. That works perfectly, without even needing to define any extra properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollViewStyle` shouldn't be assigned to the `style` member of a non-`ScrollView` class, *even if it inherits from `ScrollView`*. The QML component inheritance hierarchy is *mirrored* by the style inheritance hierarchy, so (as pointed out by BaCaRoZzo in a comment) the `style` member of a `TextArea` is actually a `TextAreaStyle`--which inherits from `ScrollViewStyle`.

So the solution is simply to define a `TextAreaStyle`, but only set the properties relevant to the `ScrollViewStyle`. Changing the word `ScrollViewStyle` to `TextAreaStyle` in the linked example is sufficient to accomplish this.